# What happens to a slave who accepts Islam?

Tags: sex, conversion, slavery, intercourse

As far as I know the slaves were non Muslim, and if there accept Islam they cannot be kept as slaves

Adwa’ al-Bayaan, 3/387

> Shaykh al-Shanqeeti (may Allaah have mercy on him) said:
>
> If it is said: If the slave is a Muslim, how can he be kept as a slave
> if the reason for which people may be taken as slaves is if they are
> kaafirs who are waging war against Allaah and His Messenger?

Source: islamqa.info
https://islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/13737

So my question is what should a master do if his slave woman wants to convert right before intercourse(or during foreplay). Should he stop or continue the act?

Comment: This is a misunderstanding on your site. In Islam it is prohibited to enslave Muslims, but if a slave converts he/she remains a slave unless the owner frees them. Mary the Coptic was a slave and mother of child of the prophet and she converted to Islam.

Comment: So, is it halal for her master to have intercourse with his slave after she converts?

Comment: Certainly, however it would be better to consider her for freeing, further the kafaras contain freeing a believing slave not any slave.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```
As far as I know the slaves were non Muslim, 
and if there accept Islam they cannot be kept as slaves
```

This is wrong. Slaves can be Muslims. There are verses in the Quran which mention Muslim (believing) slaves such as  [4:25](https://quran.com/4/25?translations=20) and [4:92](https://quran.com/4/92?translations=20) and  [2:221](https://quran.com/2/221?translations=20). The actual rule is that only a Harbi Kafir can be enslaved while a Free Muslim can never be enslaved. This says nothing about a disbeliever who is first enslaved and later accepts Islam.

It is possible for Muslim slaves to exist through the following means:

- A Harbi disbeliever who has been captured and then accepts Islam can be enslaved.
- A slave who converts to Islam remains a slave.
- A child of a Muslim slave woman through marriage with other than its owner, is a slave.

The quote you have given from *Adwa’ al-Bayaan* of al-Shanqeeti says the same. You have only given a partial quote which is a question that Shanqeeti answers and you seem to have ignored the answer. Shanqeeti says the following:

> If it is said: If the slave is a Muslim, how can he be kept as a
> slave if the reason for which people may be taken as slaves is if they
> are kaafirs who are waging war against Allaah and His Messenger?
>
> **The
> answer** is that the basic principle which is well known to the scholars
> and all wise people is that a right that is already established by
> shar’i means cannot be superceded by rights that are established later
> on.
>
> When the Muslims take prisoners of war, they are given the right to
> enslave them by the law of the Creator of all, and He is the All-Wise,
> All-Aware. If this right is established, then the slave becomes a
> Muslim after that, his right to be freed from slavery because of his
> Islam is superceded by the right of the mujaahid whose right to
> enslave him took effect before he was a Muslim. It is not just or fair
> to waive the former right because of a latter right, as is well known
> to all wise people

You wrote:

```
what should a master do if his slave woman wants to convert
```

He does not have to do anything as conversion to Islam of a concubine makes no difference. As noted above she remains a slave. And also sexual relations via concubinage remain permissible with her. Indeed, her being a Muslim, Jewess or Christian is actually requirement for concubinage according to the majority opinion.

> أن تكون الجارية مسلمة أو كتابية إذا كان المتسري مسلما
>
> For a Muslim master the concubine must be a Muslim or Kitabee
>
> <sup>— [Encyclopedia of Islamic Jurisprudence](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/6870#p1)</sup>

---

**Ref:**

> قال: إني مسلم. فقال: لو قلتها وأنت تملك أمرك أفلحت كل الفلاح ... ففدي بالرجلين
>
> (the prisoner said): I am (now) a Muslim. (The Prophet said): Had you said this when you had been the master of yourself, you would have gained every success ... he was then ransomed for two persons.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1641a) - [Sharah:](https://shamela.ws/book/1711/2444) إذا أسلمت  بعد الأسر فيسقط الخيار في قتلك ويبقى الخيار بين الاسترقاق والمن والفداء</sup>

<sub>**Note:** This answer is with respect to a Muslim master. If a Dhimmi  possesses a slave who is a Muslim then that slave must be sold to a Muslim owner. As disbelievers can not have authority over muslims under Islamic laws.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't read the fatwa properly.

Slaves converting to Islam does not necessitate that they should be freed. However, obviously, it is recommended to free slaves.